# Why my program can run in Xcode, but cannot running as a separate app?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

My program loads some data from a file and then draws them.

The file-reading part is like this:

```
- (void)load_file
{
    NSFileHandle *inFile = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:@"map_data"];
    NSData  *myData=[inFile readDataToEndOfFile];
    NSString *myText=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:myData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSArray *values = [myText componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
    for (NSString *string in values) {
        NSArray *lines=[string componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
        if ([lines count] != 2) break;
        NSPoint point= NSMakePoint([lines[0] floatValue], [lines[1] floatValue]);
        [points addObject:[NSValue valueWithPoint:point]];
    }
    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}
```

When debugging, I put the data file in the directory of [NSBundle mainBundle], and the program works fine.

However, when I use achieve to take the app out, it never runs. I put the data file in the same path with the app, but it seems fail to load it.

---

Update

I tried to use c++, but still fails.

```
- (void)load_file
{
    ifstream inf("map_data");
    double x, y;
    while (inf >> x >> y) [points addObject:[NSValue valueWithPoint:NSMakePoint(x, y)]];
    inf.close();
}
```

I tried to change the build scheme to release and run, which is fine. But whenever I go directly into the finder of app and double click it, it does not work and seems nothing is loaded.

Comment: You have to do an archive build and share it out to the Finder. You can't run a debug build directly from the Finder.

Comment: @matt, I know and I did so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how relative paths are handled by `NSFileHandle`, but usually you set up paths using the `NSBundle` class.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myfile" ofType:@"ext"];
```

You can also simply initialize an NSString from the contents of a file, you don't need to first read it into an `NSData` using `NSFileHandle`.

```
NSString *text = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path 
                                   encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:nil];
```

(Use the error parameter, if you want proper error handling)

Comment: It does not work, and I think the path is not correct. For in your code, path is "~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/graph_drawer-dnqhjikipiupyeecmplqquxxkvsp/Build/Products/Debug/graph_drawer.app/Contents/Resources/map_data", but my map_data file lies in the same directory with the app, namely "~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/graph_drawer-dnqhjikipiupyeecmplqquxxkvsp/Build/Products/Debug/map_data"

Comment: Why do you put a file next to the app? That's not how you usually do it. Either you put the file in the app bundle (in the app package) as specified by the first path you posted or you put it in ~/Library/Application Support/YourApp

Answer (score 2):

- add the file to the project as a Resource (this will cause it to be copied into the app wrapper in the right spot)
- use `[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"map_data" ofType:nil];

That should give you the path to the file.  The file should not be manually copied, it should not be next to the app wrapper, nor should you [conjecture] ever try changing or replacing the file once it is in your app wrapper.

The reason why it seems to work sometimes is mere coincidence.  You are passing a partial path to `NSFileHandle` and it happens that the current working directory of your app sometimes points to the right spot such that the data file is available.